# custom template asp.mvc problem

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have strongly typed View, custom template for properties of string type, i should change value

```
// model
class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

// view
@model Person
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
</div

//custom template view
@model System.String
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, Model.ToUpper())
```

but it doesn't work — i get old Name value, not changed

**NEW**

i forgot important detail — Name property get value from query string in URL —

```
http://localhost:53494/?Name=blah
```

Comment: what does it give you instead?

Comment: it give old Model.Name, value doesn't change

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean under not working?

Comment: i try change value for Name field, but i get original value from query string in url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html helpers such as `TextBox` always first look into modelstate when binding their value and because there is already a value coming from the request string it ignores the second argument you are passing to it. So to achieve what you are looking for you might need to first remove the value from model state:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewData.ModelState.Remove(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""));
}
@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, (Model ?? string.Empty).ToUpper())
```