# Again about custom templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Some times ago I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566089/custom-template-asp-mvc-problem) about problem with custom template. 
I find solution to use not-strongly typed view for custom template (for `double` typed properties):

```
@{
   string id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("");
   string name = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("");
   string value = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model);
} 
<input type="text" id="@id" name="@name" value="@value" />
```

But I can't find information about how method from TemplateInfo gets the name and id? What parametr I should pass to them, if property is complex-type object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They default to `HtmlFieldPrefix`

```
public string GetFullHtmlFieldName(string partialFieldName)
{
    return (this.HtmlFieldPrefix + "." + (partialFieldName ?? string.Empty)).Trim(new char[] { '.' });
}


public string GetFullHtmlFieldId(string partialFieldName)
{
    return HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(this.GetFullHtmlFieldName(partialFieldName));
}
```

Inside your partial view, you can even set the `HtmlFieldPrefix` to something from your view model

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Model.MyPrefix; // MOdel refers to your view model instance
```

On a related note, take a look here: http://btburnett.com/2011/03/correcting-mvc-3-editorfor-template-field-names-when-using-collections.html

Comment: Thanks for answer! 
Can you explain, what is HtmlFieldPrefix purpose? If it possible, with example :-)

Comment: Since you asked for example, here's an excellent article: http://davybrion.com/blog/2011/01/prefixing-input-elements-of-partial-views-with-asp-net-mvc/